# Добавления ветки Nested Set

Tags: mysql, nested-sets

Есть таблица, мне например, нужно добавить к Польше Любельское воеводство, сама ветка Польши пуста. Для создания страны, я использую вот такой код, но он требует ID левого элемента, а у нас ветка пустая

```
BEGIN;

SELECT @treeRight := rgt FROM geo
WHERE id = 16; /* справа от ветки Польща */

UPDATE geo SET rgt = rgt + 2 WHERE rgt > @treeRight;
UPDATE geo SET lft = lft + 2 WHERE lft > @treeRight;

INSERT INTO geo VALUES(0, 'Росія', @treeRight + 1, @treeRight + 2, 2);

COMMIT;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE geo SET geo.rgt = geo.rgt + 2, geo.lft = IF(geo.lft > $right_key, geo.lft + 2, geo.lft) WHERE geo.rgt >= $right_key

INSERT INTO geo SET geo.lft = $right_key, geo.rgt = $right_key + 1, level = $level + 1, name = '$name'
```

[Подробнее тут](http://www.getinfo.ru/article610.html)